# What's the meaning of function eval() in torch.nn module

Tags: pytorch

Official comment shows that "This has any effect only on modules such as Dropout or BatchNorm." But I don't understand its implementation.

Comment: it's simple and straightforward, dropout and batchnorm are disabled in the evaluation mode if you have such steps in your model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does model.eval() do in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 29):

Dropout and BatchNorm (and maybe some custom modules) behave differently during training and evaluation. You must let the model know when to switch to eval mode by calling `.eval()` on the model.

This sets `self.training` to `False` for every module in the model. If you are implementing your own module that must behave differently during training and evaluation, you can check the value of `self.training` while doing so.

Comment: In the official PyTorch tutorial (60 Minute Blitz, Training A Classifier), they did not use `.eval()` when switching to evaluation (the test set). Maybe they didn't use it because there were no Dropout or Batchnorm layers. But I think from an educational standpoint they should have used it anyway (even if it would have no effect) or at least mentioned it since it's required in the general case =/

Comment: PyTorch code mentions `self.train(False)`, and not `self.training` like it is written in the previous answer, cf. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.eval (perhaps a recent change though). @xjcl as PyTorch documentation says, "This has any effect only on certain modules.", so I guess you can systematically use it without trouble, cf. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.eval