# What does model.eval() do in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

When should I use `.eval()`? I understand it is supposed to allow me to "evaluate my model". How do I turn it back off for training?

Example training [code](https://github.com/natanielruiz/deep-head-pose/blob/master/code/train_hopenet.py) using `.eval()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does model.train() do in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch)

Comment: is there a flag to detect if the model is in eval mode? e.g. `mdl.is_eval()`?

Comment: I recommend for any questions regarding any tool with nice documentation, look into documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html . If documentation is not clear - just small comment some computation blocks working in different modes in training/optimization variables and use it for make prediction. One example is that model: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167

Comment: it simple changes the `self.training` via `self.training = training` recursively for all modules by doing `self.train(False)`. In fact that is what `self.train` does, changes the flag to true recursively for all modules. see code: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/6e1a5b1196aa0277a2113a4bca75b6e0f2b4c0c8/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1432

Answer (score 377, accepted):

`model.eval()` is a kind of switch for some specific layers/parts of the model that behave differently during training and inference (evaluating) time. For example, Dropouts Layers, BatchNorm Layers etc. You need to turn them off during model evaluation, and `.eval()` will do it for you. In addition, the common practice for evaluating/validation is using `torch.no_grad()` in pair with `model.eval()` to turn off gradients computation:

```py
# evaluate model:
model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    ...
    out_data = model(data)
    ...
```

BUT, don't forget to turn back to `training` mode after eval step:

```py
# training step
...
model.train()
...
```

Comment: model.train() also sets torch.no_grad back on?

Comment: `torch.no_grad()` is a context manager, so you should use it in a form of `with torch.no_grad():`, that guarantees when leaving `with ...` block model will turn on gradients computations automatically

Comment: so, `model.train()` and `model.eval()` have effect only on Layers, not on gradients, by default grad comp is switch on, but using context manager `torch.no_grad()` during evaluation allows you easily turn off and then autimatically turn on gradients comp at the end

Comment: Here is some additional info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch

Comment: Why do we need to turn off grad comp on Eval?

Comment: @shtse8 we don't compute or use gradients during evaluation, so turning off the autograd will speed up execution and will reduce memory usage

Comment: Does `model.eval()` or `model.train()` work recursively?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN yes! They work recursively, it looks like this for `.eval()`: `for module in self.children(): module.train(False)` and `for module in self.children(): module.train(True)` for `.train()`

Comment: is there a flag to detect if the model is in eval mode? e.g. `mdl.is_eval()`?

Comment: @CharlieParker model.training will be True if it is in train mode and False if it is in eval mode.

Comment: I think `torch.inference_mode()` is [now preferred](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-torch-no-grad-vs-torch-inference-mode/134099/2?u=timgianitsos) over `torch.no_grad()`.

Answer (score 89):

| [`model.train()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66526891/9067615) | `model.eval()` |
| --- | --- |
| Sets model in **train**ing mode: • normalisation layers<sup>1</sup> use per-batch statistics • activates `Dropout` layers<sup>2</sup> | Sets model in **eval**uation (inference) mode: • normalisation layers use running statistics • de-activates `Dropout` layers |
|  | Equivalent to `model.train(False)`. |

You can turn off evaluation mode by running `model.train()`. You should use it when running your model as an inference engine - i.e. when testing, validating, and predicting (though practically it will make no difference if your model does not include any of the [differently behaving layers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66526891/9067615)).

---

1. e.g. `BatchNorm`, `InstanceNorm`
2. This includes sub-modules of RNN modules [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534762/which-pytorch-modules-are-affected-by-model-eval-and-model-train).

Answer (score 21):

[`model.eval`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.eval) is a method of [`torch.nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html):

> #### `eval()`
>
> Sets the module in evaluation mode.
>
> This has any effect only on certain modules. See documentations of particular modules for details of their behaviors in training/evaluation mode, if they are affected, e.g. [`Dropout`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html#torch.nn.Dropout), `BatchNorm`, etc.
>
> This is equivalent with [`self.train(False)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=eval#torch.nn.Module.train).

The opposite method is [`model.train`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51433411/5884955) explained nicely by Umang Gupta.

Comment: is there a flag to detect if the model is in eval mode? e.g. `mdl.is_eval()`?

Comment: Yes, @CharlieParker `self.training` flag as explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/56828547/5884955

Answer (score 3):

An extra addition to the above answers:

I recently started working with [Pytorch-lightning](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-lightning/), which wraps much of the boilerplate in the training-validation-testing pipelines.

Among other things, it makes `model.eval()` and `model.train()` near redundant by allowing the `train_step` and `validation_step` callbacks which wrap the `eval` and `train` so you never forget to.

Comment: sorry I saw `delete` not `elaborate`. a bit dyslectic.to the question: Lightning handles the train/test loop for you, and you only have to define `train_step` and `val_step` and so on. the `model.eval()` and `model.train()` are done in he background, and you don't have to worry about them. I recommend you watch some of their videos, it is a well worth 30 minute investment.