# Pytorch: Converting a VGG model into a sequential model, but getting different outputs

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

**Background:**
I'm working on an adversarial detector method which requires to access the outputs from each hidden layer.
I loaded a pretrained VGG16 from `torchvision.models`.

To access the output from each hidden layer, I put it into a sequential model:

```
vgg16 = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)

vgg16_seq = nn.Sequential(*(
    list(list(vgg16.children())[0]) + 
    [nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((7, 7)), nn.Flatten()] + 
    list(list(vgg16.children())[2])))
```

Without `nn.Flatten()`, the forward method will complaint about dimensions don't match between `mat1` and `mat2`.

I looked into the *torchvision* [VGG](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/d3d393672b877f80fedd2d11de6b84fb19599c2e/torchvision/models/vgg.py) implementation, it uses the `[feature..., AvgPool, flatten, classifier...]` structure.
Since `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` layer and `Flatten` layer have **no parameters**, I assume this should work, but I have different outputs.

```
output1 = vgg16(X_small)
print(output1.size())
output2 = vgg16_seq(X_small)
print(output2.size())
torch.equal(output1, output2)
```

**Problem:** They are in the same dimension but different outputs.

> torch.Size([32, 1000])
> torch.Size([32, 1000])
> False

I tested the outputs right after the `AdaptiveAvgPool2d`  layer, the outputs are equal:

```
output1 = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg16.children())[:2])(X_small)
print(output1.size())
output2 = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg16_seq)[:32])(X_small)
print(output2.size())
torch.equal(output1, output2)
```

> torch.Size([32, 512, 7, 7])
> torch.Size([32, 512, 7, 7])
> True

Can someone point out what went wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the eval mode before doing inference.

i.e.

```
vgg16.eval()
vgg16_seq.eval()
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you explain why? If the mode is wrong, why `nn.Sequential(*list(vgg16.children())[:2])(X_small)`  and `nn.Sequential(*list(vgg16_seq)[:32])(X_small)` get the same outputs?

Comment: I think it's most probably due to dropout (in layer 35 and 38), as by default it's enabled in training mode, but we don't want it in inference (disabled in eval mode). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch).