# How to check if a model is in train or eval mode in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

How to check from within a model if it is currently in train or eval mode?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [the Pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/check-if-model-is-eval-or-train/9395), with a small tweak:

use

```
if self.training:
    # it's in train mode
else:
    # it's in eval mode
```

Always better to have a stack overflow answer than to look at forums.

[Explanation about the modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch)