# forward() using Pytorch Lightning not giving consistent binary classification results for single VS multiple images

Tags: pytorch, classification, autoencoder, image-classification, pytorch-lightning

I have trained a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) with an additional fully connected layer after the encoder for binary image classification. It is setup using PyTorch Lightning. The encoder / decoder is `resnet18` from PyTorch Lightning Bolts repo.

```py
from pl_bolts.models.autoencoders.components import (
    resnet18_encoder,
    resnet18_decoder
)

class VariationalAutoencoder(LightningModule):

...

    self.first_conv: bool = False
    self.maxpool1: bool = False
    self.enc_out_dim: int = 512
    self.encoder = resnet18_encoder(first_conv, maxpool1)
    self.fc_object_identity = nn.Linear(self.enc_out_dim, 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        x_encoded = self.encoder(x)
        mu = self.fc_mu(x_encoded)
        log_var = self.fc_var(x_encoded)
        p, q, z = self.sample(mu, log_var)

        x_classification_score = torch.sigmoid(self.fc_object_identity(x_encoded))

        return self.decoder(z), x_classification_score

variational_autoencoder = VariationalAutoencoder.load_from_checkpoint(
        checkpoint_path=str(checkpoint_file_path)
    )

with torch.no_grad():
    predicted_images, classification_score = variational_autoencoder(test_images)
```

The reconstructions work well for single images and multiple images when passed through `forward()`. However, when I pass multiple images to `forward()` I get different results for the classification score than if I pass a single image tensor:

```py
# Image 1 (class=1) [1, 3, 64, 64]
x_classification_score = 0.9857

# Image 2 (class=0) [1, 3, 64, 64]
x_classification_score = 0.0175

# Image 1 and 2 [2, 3, 64, 64]
x_classification_score =[[0.8943],
                         [0.1736]]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide the architecture for the encoder. You are probably not running the evaluation mode of PyTorch, hence results are different. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch) for more info.

Comment: Ah, thanks @szymonmaszke that seems to be it. I have added ```variational_autoencoder.eval()``` before the ```with torch.no_grad():``` line and the results are now consistent. So without ```eval()``` the network is changing its architecture between inferencing the first image and second one when passing multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `resnet18` which has a `torch.nn.BatchNorm2d` layer.

Its behavior changes whether it is in `train` or `eval` mode. It calculates mean and variance **across batch** during training and hence its output is dependent on examples in this batch.

In evaluation mode `mean` and `variance` gathered during training via **moving average** are used which is batch independent, hence results are the same.