# How to implement batch normalization merging in python?

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-normalization

I have defined the model as in the code below, and I used batch normalization merging to make 3 layers into 1 linear layer.

- The first layer of the model is a linear layer and there is **no bias**.
- The second layer of the model is a batch normalization and there is no weight and bias ( **affine is false** )
- The third layer of the model is a linear layer.

The variables named **new_weight** and **new_bias** are the weight and bias of the newly created linear layer, respectively.

My question is: Why is the output of the following two print functions different? And where is the wrong part in the code below the batch merge comment?

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

learning_rate = 0.01
in_nodes = 20
internal_nodes = 8
out_nodes = 9
batch_size = 100

# model define
class M(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(M, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(in_nodes, internal_nodes, bias=False)
        self.layer2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(internal_nodes, affine=False)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(internal_nodes, out_nodes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        return x


# optimizer and criterion
model = M()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()


# training
for batch_num in range(1000):
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    input = torch.randn(batch_size, in_nodes)
    target = torch.ones(batch_size, out_nodes)
    
    output = model(input)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


# batch merge
divider = torch.sqrt(model.layer2.eps + model.layer2.running_var)

w_bn = torch.diag(torch.ones(internal_nodes) / divider)
new_weight = torch.mm(w_bn, model.layer1.weight)
new_weight = torch.mm(model.layer3.weight, new_weight)

b_bn = - model.layer2.running_mean / divider
new_bias = model.layer3.bias + torch.squeeze(torch.mm(model.layer3.weight, b_bn.reshape(-1, 1)))



input = torch.randn(batch_size, in_nodes)
print(model(input))
print(torch.t(torch.mm(new_weight, torch.t(input))) + new_bias)
```

Comment: You need to pin down your problem, you have too many components in your code. Start by removing the training loop which seems irrelevant here and perform step by step tests to compare between your results and the model's intermediate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** As far as I can tell you need a `model.eval()` before the line

```
input = torch.randn(batch_size, in_nodes)
```

such that the end looks like this

```
...
model.eval()
input = torch.randn(batch_size, in_nodes)
test_input = torch.ones(batch_size,internal_nodes)/100
print(model(input))
print(torch.t(torch.mm(new_weight, torch.t(input))) + new_bias)
```

with that (I tested it) the two `print`-statements should output the same. It fixed the weights.

**Long Answer:**

When using `Batch-Normalization` according to [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm1d.html) a default `momentum` of 0.1 is used to compute the `running_mean` and `running_var`. The momentum defines how much the estimated statistics and how much the new observed value influence the value.

Now when you don't set a `model.eval()` statement the `batch_normalization` computes an updated `running_mean` and `running_var` due to the momentum in line

```
print(model(input))
```

For further details and or confirmation: [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch), [PyTorch-Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.eval)