# what does model.eval() do for batch normalization layer?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Why does the testing data use the mean and variance of the all training data? To keep the distribution consistent? What is the difference between the BN layer using model.train compared to model.val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixes the `mean` and `var` computed in the training phase by keeping estimates of it in `running_mean` and `running_var`. See [PyTorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html).

As noted there the implementation is based on the description in the paper [Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) As one tries to use the whole training data one can get (given similar data train/test data) a better estimate of the mean/var for the (unseen) test set.

Also similar questions have been asked here: [What does model.eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch)

Comment: Why use the variance and mean of the training dataset instead of the variance and mean of the testing dataset

Comment: Assuming that the training data is a larger set which should represent the real data (testing data) it is better to use this. Assume you treat patients in a hospital. When you've finished training your model you begin to treat each patient one by one. Why would you then use (test-data) to normalize. The point of it is to normalize the way the model benefits the most in training phase.