# CNN inference different results on each run

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a trained PyTorch CNN model that is attempting to classify 7 different blocks. When I run inference on the same batch of images each run gives different results, for example,

```
=====================
Run 1
pred    truth   match
=====================
block_1 block_0 no
block_1 block_1 yes
block_1 block_1 yes
block_1 block_2 no
block_1 block_2 no
block_1 block_2 no
block_1 block_3 no
block_6 block_3 no
block_6 block_3 no
block_1 block_4 no
block_1 block_4 no
block_1 block_5 no
block_1 block_5 no
block_1 block_6 no
block_1 block_6 no

=====================
Run 2 
pred    truth   match
=====================
block_3 block_0 no
block_3 block_1 no
block_3 block_1 no
block_3 block_2 no
block_3 block_2 no
block_6 block_2 no
block_3 block_3 yes
block_3 block_3 yes
block_3 block_3 yes
block_3 block_4 no
block_3 block_4 no
block_3 block_5 no
block_3 block_5 no
block_3 block_6 no
block_3 block_6 no
```

My model loader code,

```
def load_model(model, model_dir='models', model_file_name='blocks.pt'):

    model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, model_file_name)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path), strict=False)

    return model
```

And my prediction function,

```
def prediction(model, device, batch_input):

    model.to(device)
    model.eval()

    data = batch_input.to(device)
    output = model(data)

    prob = F.softmax(output, dim=1)
    pred_prob = prob.data.max(dim=1)[0]
    pred_index = prob.data.max(dim=1)[1]

    return pred_index.cpu().numpy(), pred_prob.cpu().numpy()
```

Batch image transforms (the same as used when training)

```
def image_common_transforms(mean=(0.4515, 0.3976, 0.3339), std=(0.3639, 0.3361, 0.3224)):

    common_transforms = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
    ])

    return common_transforms
```

I was under the impression that `model.eval()` would stop any random behaviour. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: `model.eval()` affects some model layers (see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018731/7750891), but it doesn't do much if you're passing in shuffled data. Check what your `batch_input` is doing.

Comment: the inputs are identical on each run, no shuffling